# google map not show in release apk using android studio

Tags: android

I am developing an app, here I'm using google map in debug mode map shows correctly but in release mode map not showing and shows only current location.

By using google map API I have tried but still its not working and also I find the SHA1 by using keystore(i.e. keytool -list -v -keystore file path.jks) then also its not working.

By using following views I tried and found the SHA1 key but map not shown in app.

[Release APK file not showing google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701865/release-apk-file-not-showing-google-maps)

How do i do?

Comment: You can refer this link {http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate}

Comment: I have created sha1 key using same method but when i put this sha1 to console to find google map api then map not shown in app with relsease mode and in debug mode map showing.

Comment: Have you check my answer?

Comment: yes i have created SHA1 key for google map api then also in relase mode map not shown

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio - Google map still blank on real Android device on release apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559602/android-studio-google-map-still-blank-on-real-android-device-on-release-apk)

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your `google_maps_key` in both **debug & release** folder in `google_maps_api.xml`. 
If not please, set it. You can find both folders inside Project structure.

See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: can i create debug and release folder? im using android studio i dont have two different folders.

Comment: From your project structure, you can find out two folders debug & release, which is created at the time of project creation. You don't need to create it.

Comment: but in my project i have not show any folder release or debug

Comment: In my app map doesnot shows but it takes current location of user in release mode, why map not shows i'm not getting but in debug mode map shows currectly.

Comment: Once you can check for demo, Create new Project by File->New->New Project->Give Application Name->Next->Next->Choose Google Maps Activity->Next->Finish. You will check difference with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Generate API key access using  release key-store. And set Google API console.

Comment: how do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to [google API console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

- crate new project
- generage API key
- enable your service
- add API key in your project

OR

You can simply follow this developer guide [LINK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start).

> If you have troubling in getting SHA-1 key. You can easily get it by running Signing-report gradle task as below picture (in Android studio).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by looking at [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/console) in the left menu select configuration, then integrity of the app and then copy the [sha1](/questions/tagged/sha1) of the upload key certificate that is below of the SHA1 Certificate of the app signing key and add it in the same API key of [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com). This way I didn't have to make changes to the [apk](/questions/tagged/apk).

If it doesn't work for you, add both and try.