# Google maps not showing on signed apk android

Tags: android, google-maps, signed-apk

In my project the Maps and everything, but when I generate a signed APK it doesn't works, I already have the "google_maps_key" in my project, I went to Google Console and put any restriction so I could test not just from my Android Device and still nothing!

Comment: sounds like you only created a debug key and not your release key too

Comment: actually  you have restricted the key to work only in your android app and if you want to see map on the release apk make sure you have added the map key in the release folder (app>src>release>res>values>google_map_api.xml)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio - Google map still blank on real Android device on release apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559602/android-studio-google-map-still-blank-on-real-android-device-on-release-apk)

Answer (score 1):

You should create a release key and add it to your project . 
[Release APK file not showing google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701865/release-apk-file-not-showing-google-maps)
This link answers you proble. It's a common problem . 
You should create a .jks file first and store it somewhere in you app folder. 
Then Create a SHA1 Fingerprint n put it on the credentials site.