# My app that uses Maps API doesn't work if downloaded from Google Play

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-play

Okay, so here is my problem:
I made a little app for myself that uses the Maps API from Google. I followed the instructions on how to put the API key in the app and all that. I make my app, run it on my phone (via USB debugging if that's important) and it works just fine. Now, out of fun, I put the app on Google Play Store (for some of my friends and family to use it idk), and all of a sudden, the app doesn't work. What happened was, the map wouldn't load (as if i haven't put in the API key). Then I uninstalled the app, tried running it with USB debugging again, and the same thing happened. So I put in the new API key, and it works just fine. Uploaded the version 2 in the Play Store, same problem and the same situation. How do I fix this? 
I will provide any additional information that you need.

Comment: maybe map API key issue. you may used debug key instead of release key

Comment: There is a release key?

Comment: it may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701865/release-apk-file-not-showing-google-maps

Comment: I've seen this, but some things are just not very straightforward (like "extract SHA-1 from keystore". How do i do that? Also, what is the terminal, because it's not cmd)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you've entered your API key within the `google_maps_api.xml` file in the release directory `(/app/src/release/res/values)` just like in your debug directory `(/app/src/main/debug/values)`.

Then, if you have API key restrictions make sure that you are using right certificates for the debug and release builds. You can get your debug and release certificates by following the steps given on Google Maps SDK for Android [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#getting-the-certificate-information-yourself)

I hope this helps! Goodluck on your project